# Importing/Exporting rules SonarLint and SonarQube

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarlint

I have a profile on SonarQube with a selected set of rules.
I've now installed SonarLint.

Is there a way to synchronize the rules in SonarLint / SonarQube ?

In principle, I would like to enable a subset of rules in SonarLint and propagate this change to SonarQube automatically (and/or the other way around), by means of importing a configuration file or something.

At the moment the only way to do it, it's by hand.

Thanks for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there is no other way of doing this than by hand. We are working on a solution. SonarLint for Visual Studio version 2 will allow you to connect SonarLint to a SonarQube server, and download some settings from there. The other direction will come later.

But as a fast solution, we are also considering generating a ruleset file on the SonarQube server. And then this file could be added manually to the projects. This fast solution would make the manual rule sharing a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, looking forward the version 2 ;)

Comment: Here is the link to the Jira ticket: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCS-552